# How does the Vaadin table work with Navigator?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm writing a view which navigates to a table entry's page displayed on the left side when a table entry (on the right) is chosen. This is similar to the addressbook tutorial on Vaadin's site, only I make use of the Navigator and views.

While I got the navigation to work (clicking on entry with id #12 navigates to localhost:8080/test/12) and a test label in the view's enter() gets changed to match the id, testTable.getItem(event.getParameters()) returns null for some reason so I can't access the entry.

The ValueChangeListener and enter() for the view are shown below.

```
    class ValueChangeListener implements Property.ValueChangeListener {
        Object testId;

        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            // Navigate to a chosen table entry
            this.testId = event.getProperty().getValue();
            navigator.navigateTo("test/" + testId);
        }
    }

    ...

    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        Object tmp = event.getParameters();
        testName.setValue((String) tmp);    // is set to the id
        System.out.println(testTable.getItem(tmp) == null);    // DEBUG: always returns true
    }
```

Comment: How do you create the `testTable`? What type of `Container` do you use?

Comment: @Krayo I use an `IndexedContainer` for the table. `createTestTable()` adds  container properties to `ic` and populates it with a for loop which adds objects to the table with `ic.addItem()` and sets the values for that object with `setValue()` before returning `ic`. The table creation is similar to the one the [address book tutorial at Vaadin uses](https://vaadin.com/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change this:

```
System.out.println(testTable.getItem(tmp) == null);
```

to this:

```
String str = (String) tmp;
if (str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(testTable.getItem(Integer.parseInt(str)) == null);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but Eclipse gives me the error ´java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""´. The test table isn't that big and parseLong gives the same error, so it can't be a case of the id exceeding the highest integer either.

Comment: @MarkusM. I edited my answer. When show the exception, at the first time?

Comment: `isEmpty()` isn't defined for Objects according to Eclipse, and its only proposal is to cast `tmp` as `AbstractField<Date>`.

Comment: Your code worked, and now I can display the entry info as it should. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong in how you manage you Navigator.
Firstly when you change view with Navigator you who should add a proper "URL fragment" with "#".
For example the Vaadin sampler uses:
http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#foundation

If in your URL there's no "#" ViewChangeEvent.getParameters() gives you **null** or *isEmpty()*.